# Sort a complex XML based on inner most child

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file containing data as shown below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <RootInner>
    <NodesMain>
      <Main>
        <Modules>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="22" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Child_1" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="DefaultChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="33" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Reject" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="200" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="Reject" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="CC" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="CC" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="3" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="19" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Child_1" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="DefaultChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="18" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Reject" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="200" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="Reject" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="AA" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="AA" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="1" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="OC11" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="OC11" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="SDMChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="OC14" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="OC14" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="SDMChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="BB" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="BB" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="2" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
        </Modules>
      </Main>
    </NodesMain>
  </RootInner>
</Root>
```

I want to sort the  element by "ModulePosition" in C#.Net. Final output should be as follows. Sample code tried by me posted below

```
<Root>
  <RootInner>
    <NodesMain>
      <Main>
        <Modules>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="19" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Child_1" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="DefaultChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="18" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Reject" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="200" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="Reject" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="AA" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="AA" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="1" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="OC11" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="OC11" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="SDMChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="OC14" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="OC14" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="SDMChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="BB" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="BB" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="2" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
          <Module>
            <Description>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="22" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Child_1" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="100" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="DefaultChild" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Descriptionettings>
                  <setting name="ChildId" value="33" />
                  <setting name="ChildName" value="Reject" />
                  <setting name="Capacity" value="200" />
                  <setting name="ChildType" value="Reject" />
                </Descriptionettings>
              </Child>
            </Description>
            <Header>
              <setting name="ModuleName" value="CC" />
              <setting name="ModuleType" value="CC" />
              <setting name="ModulePosition" value="3" />
            </Header>
          </Module>
        </Modules>
      </Main>
    </NodesMain>
  </RootInner>
</Root>
```

I am using XDocument to load contents and orderby linq expression to sort. But the results are not accurate, sample code below

```
var documents2 = xDoc.Descendants("Module").OrderBy(x => (int)(x.Elements("attribute").First().Attribute("value"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want to sort using an XSLT transform or directly in Java?

Comment: @JimGarrison To do it in C#

Comment: Then why did you tag the question XSLT? Using the XSLT tag attracts people who will tell you (rightly) that this is far easier in XSLT than in C#.

Comment: @MichaelKay removed the XSLT tag. Added C# tag

Comment: You could always parse the XML document into list of objects and then sort the list using LINQ.

Comment: @Asunez Thanks this helped me finally..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT you can sort the `Module` children of the `Modules` element as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Modules">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Module">
              <xsl:sort select="Header/setting[@name = 'ModulePosition']/@value" data-type="number"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5h

With LINQ and C# you could use

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

        foreach (XElement modules in doc.Descendants("Modules"))
        {
            modules.ReplaceNodes(
                modules
                .Elements("Module")
                .OrderBy(m => (int)m.Element("Header").Elements("setting").First(s => (string)s.Attribute("name") == "ModulePosition").Attribute("value")).ToList()
                );
        }

        doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: your solution really works. but I want something in C#, can you help there? Thanks in advance